# Running multiple Coded UI test from same page

Tags: visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm pretty new to coded ui test, and I'm still learning...

I need to create and run a lot of test (through OrderedTest) on a particular web page inside a required login area.

Obviously I don't want to open a new browser window and perform a login for each test, but i can't figure how to start each test from the same point.

The only thing i understood so far is that I don't have to code the "open browser" and "login" actions inside `[TestInitialize]`

Answer (score 0):

We generally do logout and login for each and every test, but I am sure this process may vary from case to case. I would not like to logout and login again and again to test a series if menu navigation test.

If all of your test are in same class then I would suggest you to write your Browser login code in `[ClassInitialize]`, so that the browser will login only once at the start of test.